# Anko how to change button color?

Tags: android-layout, button, android-button, anko

I`m trying to change the color of a button inside a LinearLayout:

```
class MoodActivityUI : AnkoComponent<MoodActivity> {
override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<MoodActivity>) = with(ui) {
    frameLayout {
        verticalLayout {

            linearLayout {
                button("3"){
                    setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("red"))
                }.lparams{
                    width = dip(53)
                    height = dip(53)
                    leftMargin=dip(6)
                }

                button("2"){
                }.lparams{
                    width = dip(53)
                    height = dip(53)}

                button("1"){
                }.lparams{
                    width = dip(53)
                    height = dip(53)}
                ...
```

It turns out to look like this:

[image]

Why its going outside of the boundaries of the button shape? 
How can I just change the button color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use "themedButton" instead of "button" like this:

```
themedButton("3", theme = R.style.MyButtonStyle) {
    }.lparams {
        width = dip(53)
        height = dip(53)
        leftMargin = dip(6)
    }
```

and style in styles.xml

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#f00</item>
</style>
```

Comment: what is the difference between your solution and this:

button("- 3"){
                        background = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.minus_3_button, null)...
  is one of them better then the other?

Comment: background = blah-blahh totally replaces button's background, no more gray rectangle with rounded corners (like on picture above). But my suggestion is just tint existed button's background.